# Time Zone of Cloud Functions for Firebase Scheduler does not change

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I am currently creating and deploying a function to be executed periodically in the Cloud Functions for Firebase scheduler as shown below.
The key point is that I want it to be executed every day at 0:05 Japan time as .timeZone('Asia/Tokyo').

The deploy itself is working fine, but when I look at the content in GCP's Cloud Scheduler, the Time Zone is set to (America/LosAngeles) as shown in the image below, and the actual execution time is off from Japan time.

I manually changed the time zone to Japan time in the Cloud Scheduler function management screen and confirmed that the desired behavior was achieved, but when I deploy the function again, it is still set to (America/LosAngeles).

I thought it might be affected by the region of GCP itself, and that I would have to change the region of GCP, but I haven't found where I can change it from.
However, I thought that I should be able to specify the .timeZone for each function from the code. I'm at a loss.

I don't know how to solve this problem, and I'm wondering if anyone can help me.

```
exports.XXX = functions.pubsub
.schedule('every day 0:05')
.timeZone('Asia/Tokyo')
.onRun((context) => {
///省略
});
```

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have experienced the same problem too. There's also a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67762715/unable-to-change-cloud-scheduler-timezone-for-pubsub-cloud-function-deploy-via-c) and the solution to downgrade the `firebase-tools` works for me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Before downgrading firebase-tools,  Upgrading `firebase-tools` to 9.12.1 and upgrade the node.js version from v14 to v16(with nvm) solved the above problem!

Comment: Same issue with the ``v12.3`` I had to update it manually in the GCP panel

Answer (score 1):

This could be related to your CLI version, Make sure it is updated and if you keep experiencing issues, you should contact firebase support to submit a bug request [**HERE**](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact?visit_id=637577623681798975-1555774277&rd=1).

Another solution is that the region could be set as undefined inside your `Google Cloud Platform (GCP) resource location`.
*Just be warned that setting the GCP location isn't recommended unless you know what you are doing and you want to set all your default locations.*

Reference: [default-cloud-location](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/locations#default-cloud-location)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried update CLI tools and deploy, but the problem is same. I also tried change GCP region with command `gcloud config set functions/region asia-northeast1`. Changing region is fine but this problem has benn not solved...

Comment: One thing that bothers me is that even after changing the region and deploying again, the region of the function remains us-central1 as shown here. What settings are affected by this?

functions[XXX(us-central1)]: Successful upsert schedule operation.

Comment: 2 main factors: the CLI compiles the code and publishes it to the relevant cloud function servers, and the default location that GCP uses and firebases' native locations. some are exclusive to us-central1 such as hosting.

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

It looks like there is a bug in version 9.12 of `firebase-tools` that forces all Cloud Functions to be deployed in pacific timezone, regardless of the timezone you set in the code.

Upgrading to version 9.12.1 should fix the problem. For further details on the problem, see this [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3425) on the Github repo.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Before downgrading firebase-tools,  Upgrading `firebase-tools` to 9.12.1 and upgrade the node.js version from v14 to v16(with nvm) solved the above problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the time zone in Firebase function.

```
exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('5 11 * * *')
    .timeZone('America/New_York')
    .onRun((context) => {
        console.log('This will be run every day at 11:05 AM Eastern!');
        return null.
    });
```

Users can choose time zone - default is "Los Angeles."