# Unable to change Cloud scheduler timezone for PubSub Cloud Function deploy via CICD

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

Suddenly the timezone for scheduler started falling back to default "America/Los_Angelos"
Look at below example from firebase docs (ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions#write_a_scheduled_function)

```
exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 11 * * *')
  .timeZone('America/New_York') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
  .onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every day at 11:05 AM Eastern!');
  return null;
});
```

Unfortunately, the timeZone started failing for all new deployment via our CI pipeline and scheduled jobs started running at 11:00 AM Pacific instead of expected 11:00 AM Eastern time.

Tried updating node in CI Pipeline, firebase-admin in package, but nothing helped...

Answer (score 1):

After all the analysis we came to understand that we had firebase-tools in our Git CI pipeline to invoke the deploy command.
It was always installing the latest firebase-tools npm module.
Recently, there was an update in this package (ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-tools)

It was after this update, that whenever the pipeline ran, the timeZone was never being set whatever be the value ("America/Costa_Rica", "America/New_York", etc.)

Finally, setting the firebase-tools version to back to "9.6.1" in pipeline, made it work.

```
- npm install -g firebase-tools@9.6.1
```

Hope it helps someone and google fixes the issue soon.